# Django tenant based users

Tags: django, multi-tenant, django-tenants

Scenerio:

1. A global user can visit any tenant
2. Different tenant will create different user of their own password
3. A general user can create account in different tenant with different password
4. Tenant superuser can create their own group with permission

Using django_tenant and django_tenant_users. But can not able to do these. Need suggestion how to achieve this using django